# How to set a boolean tag in a try/ catch and getting the result

Tags: java, boolean, try-catch

I have a simple case , so I'm using a try/ catch and a boolean variable isInserted as bellow , at the end of my code I have to do some treatement based on the value of isInserted , my question is why is it always equal to false even I m sure and I tested that it should be true in some cases  ,  how I can solve this  :

```
AtomicReference<Boolean> isInserted = new AtomicReference<>(false);
try {
//treatement
isInserted.set(true);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
//treatement
isInserted.set(false)
}
if (isInserted.get() == true ) {
//treatement
}
```

how I can solve this, please help

Comment: It would only not be set to true if you never hit the line which sets it to true (or, if there's a line after which sets it back to false).

Comment: Also: `AtomicBoolean` is better than `AtomicReference<Boolean>`; but why do you need anything more than a `boolean` anyway?

Comment: Do you have any other code in your `try` section that throws `DataIntegrityViolationException` and therefore `isInserted` is quietly set to false?

Comment: I tested your code snippet - it's worked fine and `isInserted` is `true` because no DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown

Comment: @AndyTurner beacause boolean doesn't work for me  ,

Comment: @marie,  you should print exception stacktrace in the `catch` section to clarify this issue

Comment: @marie can you explain why boolean wouldn't work? For example, do you have a requirement of effective finality?

Comment: @AlexRudenko no there s not , the only statement i have in try section is  inserted.set(true), yeah I ll print the exception  ; it may helps

Comment: @AndyTurner it gives me an error, I don't remember what is it exactly  , even I do it as usual , Boolean isInserted = false ; then I set it isInserted = true ...